# Does anyone know what it means: "getSlotFromBufferLocked: encountered NULL buffer in slot 0 looking for buffer"

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've create subclass of TextureView, all works fine, but always after pause/resume activity i'v got message like this

> 05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: encountered NULL buffer in slot 0 looking for
>   buffer 0xba3458 05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   00: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.865:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   01:
>   0xcecb08 05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   02: 0xba3458 05-29 13:02:33.865:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   03: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   04: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.865:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   05: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   06: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.865:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   07: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   08: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.865:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   09: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.865: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   10: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   11: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   12: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   13: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   14: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   15: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   16: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   17: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   18: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   19: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   20: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   21: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   22: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   23: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   24: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   25: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   26: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   27: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   28: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   29: NULL
>   05-29 13:02:33.873: DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745):
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked:   30: NULL 05-29 13:02:33.873:
>   DEBUG/SurfaceTextureClient(8745): getSlotFromBufferLocked:   31: NULL

On pause i destroy my gl surface and gl context and terminate display, on resume create new surface and context and obtain display. All works fine, but I think it shouldn't be such message in device log.

Does anyone know what does it mean, and why it could happen. Thank you.

Comment: might be related somehow http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26177